# Compare length of sound file in bash

Tags: shell, audio, terminal, wav, sox

I want to have a shell script, that checks the length of a sound file and check if the length is shorter, than a specified length. But I keep getting an error message "command not found" at the if-statement.

```
#!/bin/bash
soundlength=$(soxi -D $1)

enter code here
if [$soundlength < $2]
then
  # do something
fi
```

I am guessing the $soundlength is a string and it's failing to compare string to int, but I can't find a solution to this.

Thanks in advance for all answers.

Comment: You likely need a space after the `[` . Otherwise, bash will think `[$soundlength` is the command instead of what you want

Comment: http://shellcheck.net will do basic debugging of this nature for you. Good luck.

Comment: Answers do not belong in the question. If you have solved your own problem, please post an answer in the "answer" box below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `soxi` returns 0 or a float -  example 27.741995,  therefore you will need `bc` or `awk` to check if the output is bigger than N, this because `bash` don't support floats.

Here is an example with `bc`:

```
#!/bin/bash

soundlength=$(soxi -D $1)

if [ 1 -eq "$(echo "${soundlength} > ${2}" | bc)" ]; then
    echo "${soundlength} is > than ${2}"
fi
```

And here is an example with `AWK`:

```
#!/bin/bash

soundlength=$(soxi -D $1)

if awk 'BEGIN{exit ARGV[1]>ARGV[2]}' "$z" "$y"; then
    echo "${soundlength} is > than ${2}"
fi
```

If you don't want to use either `bc` of `awk` you could give a try to [zsh](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Arithmetic-Evaluation.html) shell, it supports floats.